# Meteor How to call global helper in template file?

Tags: meteor

I have created global helper in app/client/lib/global_helper.js

```
Template.registerHelper("getImages", id => {
  if(id){
    let user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: id});
    try {
      if (user.profile.picture) {
        return user.profile.picture;
      } else {
        return "http://api.adorable.io/avatars/150/"+id+".png";
      }
    }catch(e) {
      return "http://api.adorable.io/avatars/150/"+id+".png";
    }
  }
});
```

and trying to call it in my html template

```
app/client/template/shared/sidebar/my_sidebar.html

<img src="{{getImages this._id}}" alt="User" class="profilepic">
```

But it's not working. Not getting what is issue.

It's working when i called it in other files 
app/client/template/pages/dashboard/dashboard.html

Comment: Are you using imports ? Maybe if you try to import the file global_helper.js before every other it can work.

Comment: @user3714488 please do ```console.log(id)``` within the helper function. To show if there is an actual id

Comment: @philip_nunoo is right. Global helpers by definition are to be used all around without the need for importing but the file that you defined them in. Most likely, there's an error with the way you're calling it.

Comment: You can easily detect, whether the helper is called using the `debugger` statement.

Comment: are you sure `this._id` is defined?

Comment: when i am doing console log it's not going in this helper registerHelper . I am not sure why it's not working. maybe my sidebar path is in "templates/shared/ "folder. But global helper should call in each file. It's working for files which are in "template/pages"  folder.

Comment: Which version of Meteor, and do you have a Meteor section in package.json?

Comment: yes when i am doing console.log in global_helper.js http://prntscr.com/l8uwop it's showing id in console.

Comment: meteor version is 1.4.1 and in package.json about which section you are talking?

Answer (score 0):

If your console is working properly then you should try `ES6` way as like `id` instead of `_id: id` see the below

```
let user = Meteor.users.findOne({ id });
```